# Get current configuration for a running helm release?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Let's say that I recently installed or upgraded a helm release, e.g.:

```
helm upgrade ... config.yaml ...
```

Is there any way for me to retrieve the `config.yaml` via helm CLI? I need to verify a config value.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want only the info about the values file used for a given release, use [`helm get values`](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_get_values/):

`helm get values RELEASE_NAME`

Take a look at [`helm get`](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_get/) docs to other options:

> This command consists of multiple subcommands which can be used to get extended information about the release, including:
>
> - The values used to generate the release
> - The generated manifest file
> - The notes provided by the chart of the release
> - The hooks associated with the release

Comment: Please update the helm get link to - https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_get_values/ and  https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_get/